# Quais os critérios para determinar se a pergunta é subjetiva?

Tags: suporte, status-intencional, localização, pergunta-subjetiva

Escrevendo uma pergunta, acabo de receber a mensagem "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed". Eu entendo como isso é feito no Stackoverflow original em inglês. Como o algoritmo sabe que a pergunta é subjetiva aqui? O algoritmo entende português?

A pergunta é [É sempre garantido que uma aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1946/e-sempre-garantindo-que-uma-aplicacao-com-multiplas-threads-rode-mais-rapido-que)

Já deu a mensagem quando coloquei o título.

Comment: Pode postar o conteúdo da pergunta aqui?

Comment: O algoritmo parece ser bastante simples: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20010, resta a dúvida se ele passou pelo processo de tradução.

Comment: Bom achado, @GuilhermeBernal! Eu acredito que o algoritmo não seja exatamente esse, e que a resposta que você linkou esteja desatualizada. Se a perguntas for [esta](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/1946), é possível que o algoritmo tenha pego a palavra "performance" – que aliás é objeto de uma [sugestão de edição](http://br.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1379) controversa.

Comment: No momento eu não tinha feito a pergunta ainda, editei p/ colocá-la agora. @bfavaretto Não me importei com a edição da pergunta citada

Comment: O gatilho parece ser `mais rápido` (adicione algo mais para completar 15 caracteres).

Comment: Talvez a ausência da tag de código aumente o 'nivel de subjetividade' da pergunta.

Comment: @perdeu Pelo que entendi, só o título é considerado. Ainda não tinha nem usado tags quando a mensagem apareceu. Mas cairia no mesmo problema, como o algoritmo sabe? Foi feito alguma localização?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, existe uma versão em português para este algoritmo. O texto de erro que você recebeu será traduzido brevemente.

> Yes, there is a Portuguese version of this algorithm. The error string you received will be localized shortly.

Answer (score 7):

Parece que o gatilho é mesmo a expressão **"mais rápido"**, como [sugeriu](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/469/quais-os-criterios-para-determinar-se-a-pergunta-e-subjetiva#comment899_469) o Guilherme Bernal. Testei os seguintes títulos:

> - sempre garantido que uma aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?
> - garantido que uma aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?
> - que uma aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?
> - uma aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?
> - aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?
> - com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?
> - múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?
> - threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?
> - rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?
> - mais rápido que usando uma única thread?
> - rápido que usando uma única thread?
> - que usando uma única thread?
> - usando uma única thread?
> - uma única thread?

Nas últimas quatro variações, a mensagem deixou de aparecer. Para confirmar, tentei "foo foo foo foo foo foo" como título. Ao acrescentar "mais rápido", a mensagem apareceu.

A motivação para isso parece ser alertar que perguntas sobre *performance* (ou desempenho, em pt) tendem a ser subjetivas.

Comment: Que legal, não pensei em fazer isso. E parece que houve alguma localização. Seria legal o Gabe dizer alguma coisa sobre isso.

Comment: Eita, o Guilherme Bernal já tinha sacado isso (ver comentário acima), e eu não tinha visto!

Comment: @bfavaretto, quando usada expressão, `qual é o melhor` também aparece aquela caixinha azul.

Comment: @perdeu `o melhor` já é suficiente. Parece estar bem feito.

Comment: @bigown Acho que o Gabe não vai dizer quais são as expressões da lista negra, para não facilitar a vida de quem tentar burlar o filtro (aliás, o sistema deixa postar mesmo com o título problemático, ou não?)

Comment: @perdeu Se o Gabe não disser qual é a lista, podemos fazer nossa própria aqui nesta pergunta, como uma resposta community wiki :)

Comment: A dúvida é saber se houve a localização e não a lista. Tem coisas que só o pessoal da equipe pode responder com propriedade, embora parece que foi feito. Mas vale chamar a atenção para o fato, porque mesmo sem nossa participação, ele pode aproveitar para dar uma revisada agora.

Comment: @bigown O M0sa respondeu!

Comment: @Gabe sim, fui quem colocou a tradução.